# Appdelegate used from pod file and access firebasemessaging pod show error of pod not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoapods

I'm badly stuck in a situation where `appdelegate` class is being used in pods because of `appdelegate` in the base project that is being used into other branches and trying to add firebase but getting an error of `"'FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging.h' file not found"` in the import, any help from you guys will save my days. I tried many solution but no luck yet, clean, restart , reinstalled pods after completely removed, did a lot times but no progress. I will give a bounty appreciation for your helps.

Please ask questions in the comments for more details.

Comment: I didn't understood the issue. Could you clarify it? You have multiple targets?

Comment: Sure, Thank you for commenting, 

I have one base project and i does all work in that and a second project where i used base project as pod and using that pod as of main source code, so it takes appdelegate file from that pod, Now the issue is i used firebase in base project and it is working in in base project when i used base project as a pod in second project it gives error of firebase library not found.

Comment: You use one project as a Pod? What's the podspec for it? Did you specified the dependencies for it?

Comment: Let me know Larme if still need any other info, We can start a small chat here. Your help will make me to give you a great bounty. I'm badly stuck from 4 days.

Comment: Yes for base i specified the dependency, and also specified in other project.

Comment: Is `FirebaseMessaging` specified in the Podfile?

Comment: Yes in the both pod files, base app and other app.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing kind of the same issue, I have solved it by clearing CocoaPods cache and redownloading it. Follow this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76538225/7728628