# How can solve this issues? 'FirebaseMessaging.h' file not found

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

How can solve this issues?   'FirebaseMessaging.h' file not found

where has problem?

I had tried to used pod install, but still issues.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code, errors and and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Lastly, images are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question. Also, take a look at [No Images Please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Can you include: your podfile (as text please), what versions of Firebase, XCode and CocoaPods you're using. You may also be missing `pod 'FirebaseCore'`

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, I have solved it by clearing CocoaPods cache and redownloading it.

Steps:

```
rm -rf "${HOME}/Library/Caches/CocoaPods"
rm -rf "`pwd`/Pods/"
```

Then go to the flutter project directory then,

```
cd ios
pod update
```

Then try to build/run the project.

Answer (score -5):

You can use this for importing the header file

> #import "FirebaseMessaging.h"

Comment: I had import it, I did not know why it show to me this error